# Angular Sortable Containment prevents drop operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, sorting

I have a horizontal sortable Angular list but the containment option doesn't work and actually prevents the dragged item from being dropped.

Here's the sortable list without a containment option - notice that you have to "shake" the boxes to make them drop sometimes:
http://jsfiddle.net/zobgawqt/

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) { alert(ui.item.index()); }
};
```

Here's the sortable list WITH a containment option:
http://jsfiddle.net/4b4jzycs/2/

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    containment: 'parent',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) { alert(ui.item.index()); }
};
```

Notice in the second version that the boxes are draggable but not droppable.

Here's a jQuery version that works with the same containment option:
http://jsfiddle.net/L7jemdbh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest example I could create that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/0sx1wnyr/1/

There is a fix for the problem with having to shake the block to drop it - you need to add a 'start' event handler: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/issues/19

```
$scope.sortableOptions = { 
    containment: "parent", 
    axis: "x", 
    tolerance: "pointer",
    start: function(e, ui) {
        $(e.target).data("ui-sortable").floating = true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `containment` property needs a common ancestor of all the sortable items. If you give it a selector of the `.sort-container` node, it works as expected:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    containment: '.sort-container',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) { alert(ui.item.index()); }
};
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b4jzycs/6/)

Comment: This works but only if the .sort-list-horizontal margin is greater than zero. Setting the margin to zero leaves us with non-droppable blocks again: http://jsfiddle.net/zy55k3ac/1/

Comment: The problem with having margins is that the blocks then move vertically which is not what I want.